# Extend or wrap the object received by canvas.getContext ()

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, webgl2

is it possible to get an object with a prototype of the received context?

```
let webgl = canvas.getContext('webgl2', params) || canvas.getContext('webgl', params) || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl', params);

    
let myObj1 = Object.create(webgl)

let myObj2 = {
    __proto__ : webgl,
    myMethod(){}
}
```

these and other variations of these methods catch the **Illegal invocation** error when referring to the standard context methods.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

There are lots of examples of wrapping the prototypes

Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.*

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.*

[Here's one that tries to catch various WebGL issues](https://github.com/greggman/webgl-lint)

I'm not sure what you mean about catching `illegal invocation` error.

If you want to wrap the function directly instead of the prototype then

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

gl.clearColor = function(origFn) {
  return function(...args) {
    console.log(`clear(${args.join(', ')})`);
    origFn.call(this, ...args);
  };
}(gl.clearColor);

gl.clearColor(0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Here's also an example of wrapping the entire object

```js
const foo = {};
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

for (let key in gl) {
  const value = gl[key];
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    wrapFunction(gl, key, foo);
  } else {
    wrapProperty(gl, key, foo);
  }
}

function wrapFunction(gl, key, wrapper) {
  const origFn = gl[key];
  wrapper[key] = function(...args) {
    return origFn.call(gl, ...args);
  };
}

function wrapProperty(gl, key, wrapper) {
  wrapper.__defineGetter__(key, function() {
    return gl[key];
  });
  wrapper.__defineSetter__(key, function(value) {
    gl[key] = value;
  });
}

foo.clearColor(1, 0.5, 0, 1); // orange
foo.clear(foo.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Example:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGLDeveloperTools/blob/master/src/debug/webgl-debug.js